# how to get vendor id and pid of usb device in qt on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, usb

I'm using qt on Windows. My program need to know vendor id and product id of plugged usb flash drive.

I was trying to implement example from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935184/how-to-get-vendor-id-and-product-id-of-a-plugged-usb-device-on-windows), but I'm getting segmentation fault on [WinUsb_Initialize function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This is my code:

```
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ ,
     FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

if(hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    qDebug() << "hDevice - INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "hDevice handle ok";
    PWINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE phWinUSBHandle;
    BOOL result = false;
    result = WinUsb_Initialize(hDevice, phWinUSBHandle); //seg
}
```

I need phWinUSBHandle to use [WinUsb_GetDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

I'll be very grateful for any help. Maybe someone knows some alternative way to get vendor id and product id in windows?

Comment: No, I didn't find.

Answer (score 1):

Have you referred `libusb` library ? It might help you.

Comment: After reading [this topic](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.libusb.devel.windows/4417), I'm afraid that libusb-win32 won't help me. I'll try libusb-win32 later. Thank you for your replay.